# Как отправить на печать страницу?

Tags: javascript, jquery, print

```
<a onclick="window.print()">Print</a>
```

Использовал для печати страницы window.print(), но она печатает ту страницу на которой находится данный код (например **a.html**), как **распечатать** другую страницу сайта (например **b.html**) по клику на кнопку на странице **a.html**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

устанавливать контент со страницы **b.html** в страницу **a.html**, после печати возвращать обратно. если страница **b.html** загружается с помощью AJAX, то

```
function(response){
    let backup = document.body.innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = response;
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML = backup;
}
```